# When using <fieldset> in HTML a line does not appear around the border

Tags: html, label, legend, fieldset

When using several forms control together with "fieldset" tag the line around them doesn't appear. I have tried it in Firefox, Chrome, Explorer and Safari and the same thing happens in all of them. This is the code I am using for it:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="get">

<fieldset>

<legend>Contact details:</legend><br>


<label for="name">Name:</label>

<input type="text" name="nom" id="name"><br><br>


<label for="surname">Surname:</label>

<input type="text" name="ape" id="surname"><br><br>


<label for="age">Age:</label>

<input type="number" name="ed" id="age" min="1" max="95"><br><br>


<label for="email">Email:</label>

<input type="email" name="em" id="email"><br><br>


<input type="submit">


</fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: It works for me in codepen. Is there some CSS that might be affecting that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap? i have tried to comment out bootstrap link from my file and the fieldset border appear.
If you included Bootstrap you might need some additional customization.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that in my CSS reset I had border:0 for the "fieldset".